# Make Makefile.am less repetitive when building a lot of similar executables (tests)

Tags: automake

I recently added a bunch of tests to a C project, with one executable per test. Adding them to `make check` was really easy, but it's starting to make the Makefile.am huge:

```
TESTS = tests/check_bitreader tests/check_cets_ecm tests/check_descriptors tests/check_mpd tests/check_psi
noinst_PROGRAMS = $(TESTS)

tests_check_bitreader_SOURCES = tests/bitreader.c tests/main.c
tests_check_bitreader_CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) $(CHECK_CFLAGS)
tests_check_bitreader_LDADD = tslib/libts.a $(LDFLAGS) $(CHECK_LIBS)

tests_check_cets_ecm_SOURCES = tests/cets_ecm.c tests/main.c
tests_check_cets_ecm_CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) $(CHECK_CFLAGS)
tests_check_cets_ecm_LDADD = tslib/libts.a $(LDFLAGS) $(CHECK_LIBS)

tests_check_descriptors_SOURCES = tests/descriptors.c tests/main.c
tests_check_descriptors_CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) $(CHECK_CFLAGS)
tests_check_descriptors_LDADD = tslib/libts.a $(LDFLAGS) $(CHECK_LIBS)

tests_check_mpd_SOURCES = tests/mpd.c tests/main.c
tests_check_mpd_CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) $(CHECK_CFLAGS)
tests_check_mpd_LDADD = tslib/libts.a $(LDFLAGS) $(CHECK_LIBS)

tests_check_psi_SOURCES = tests/psi.c tests/main.c
tests_check_psi_CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) $(CHECK_CFLAGS)
tests_check_psi_LDADD = tslib/libts.a $(LDFLAGS) $(CHECK_LIBS)
```

I was able to avoid repeating myself with `TESTS` and `noinst_PROGRAMS`, but is there a way to avoid all of these duplicate `tests_check_*_SOURCES`, `CFLAGS`, `LDADD`, etc.? In a normal Makefile, I could do a rule like `test_%: %.c:` (or something), but I'm not aware of the options in Makefile.am.

Comment: I think you can avoid repeating `CFLAGS` and `LDADD`. These general name apply to all programs. I can not think anything for the sources.

Comment: You would be better off descending into `tests` and using a `Makefile.am` there - unless you're trying to keep everything 'flat' - to take advantage of global `LDADD`, etc., and `AM_DEFAULT_SOURCE_EXT`.

Comment: @BrettHale If I created a tests/Makefile.am, wouldn't I still need to write all of the same lines, just without the `tests_` prefix?